# How to get a child tab to open by default when parent tab is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I have a tab page set up and I need the first sub tab to also open when the main tab is opened.  Right now you have to click one tab then click the second which gets annoying.

This is a code pen to view it live

```
jQuery('#interest_tabs').on('click', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function(e) 
{
e.preventDefault();
var $link = $(this);
if (!$link.parent().hasClass('active')) {
//remove active class from other tab-panes
jQuery('.tab-content:not(.' + $link.attr('href').replace('#','') + ') 
.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
// click first submenu tab for active section
jQuery('a[href="' + $link.attr('href') + '_all"][data- 
toggle="tab"]').click();
// activate tab-pane for active section
jQuery('.tab-content.' + $link.attr('href').replace('#','') + ' .tab- 
pane:first').addClass('active');
}
});
```

This is the current code for the tabs

https://codepen.io/frisco3rd/pen/PrzWNd?editors=1010

So you should be able to click the top tab and when that opens the sub tab the 1st option should be shown also by default

Comment: i updated it now with the js in the right spot before it was at the very bottom of the html https://codepen.io/frisco3rd/pen/PrzWNd?editors=1010

Comment: Ah. my bad - didn't see it right down there so assumed the tabs were being controlled by bootstrap.  Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 0):

Try this animation is added to it as well ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("ul.top li").hover(function () { //When trigger is hovered...
    $(this).children("ul.sub").slideDown('fast');
}, function () {
    $(this).children("ul.sub").slideUp('slow');
});
});
```

[Working Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kd6kQ/1)

Comment: Hi, there's not a lot of code in the fiddle - can you copy it into a Stack Overflow snippet?  Better to keep all the code in one place (etc).  It's very similar to jsfiddle, with some minor changes how to specify jquery include and the like